# Arduino Uno + ESP8266 + Cayenne = Not Working (Currently)

Tags: c#, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

So I'm new with Arduino Uno and wanted to make a smart food dispenser for my cat.

I used the esp 8266 + Arduino Uno and used the Cayenne as the IOT builder platform based on this video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n34YOU6drEw&t=133s

Unfortunately it did not work (the serial monitor said,"esp not responding"). Can somebody tell me how to make it work?

Thanks

Plus I can't login to the Cayenne forum for some reason...

Comment: Please, add the code that you have. This is more useful for people who might want to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work on arduino uno. I try it on arduino mega and it is working well.